# What is generating my meta og:description?

Tags: plugins, post-meta, facebook, excerpt

My [site](http://www.superlogical.net/art/movie/2011/07/first-look-at-dwarves-from-the-hobbit/) has Facebook social graph meta tags in its page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="First Look at Dwarves from The Hobbit"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Movie"/>
```

The only Facebook-related plugin I have installed [Facebook Page Publish](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-page-publish/).

Why is it only picking up the category of the post?  There are no options to configure the og meta tags of this plugin.

**UPDATE**

I now figure I can use the post excerpt as the value for og:description, but whenever I use either of these functions:

- get_the_excerpt();
- the_excerpt();

the page outputs the following code:

```
<!-- AddThis Button Begin -->
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_product = 'wpp-261';
var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true,"ui_508_compliant":true};</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4df74bc61d613ae9"></script>"/>
```

I then configured the AddThis Wordpress plugin to remove Add This from the post excerpt, but the same code is still spat out by the excerpt functions.

Comment: The latter part of your question seems unrelated to what it was in first place. Please consider asking new question for newer separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook Page Publish plugin is adding the og:description.  Looking through the code in fpp_index.php at lines 843 - 851:

```
    $description = array();
    if ($options['show_post_author']) {
            $description[] = esc_attr(fpp_get_post_author($post));/*, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')*/
    }
    if ($options['show_post_categories']) {
            $categories = esc_attr(fpp_get_post_categories($post));/*, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')*/
            if (!empty($categories)) $description[] = $categories;
    }
    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="'.implode(' | ', $description).'"/>';
```

It appears that you have only checked the "post categories" option and have unchecked "post author" on the [plugin admin page](http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=facebook-page-publish/fpp_index.php). See this [screenshot](http://min.us/le304W).

That's the option the plugin is using the generate the og:description.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is that I was expecting the og:description to be more than the lowest-level category of the page.  I thought it would essentially have an equivalent value to the meta description.

Answer (score 1):

These OG Meta tags are reported as errors by validator.w3.org:

Line 34, Column 16: there is no attribute "property"

You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).

This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.

How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.